# I need to convert decimal or money to int

Tags: c#, asp.net, type-conversion, int, currency

I try to convert this number to `int` in C#, but I can't.

**800,000.00** is the original number, I need **800000**.

I used that line, but it didn't work.

```
value = int.Parse(Txt_proyeccion.Text, NumberStyles.Any | NumberStyles.Number);
```

That original number is in a textbox in asp app.

thanks!

Comment: `int.Parse("800,000.00", NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands);`

Comment: `value=(int)decimal.Parse(Txt_proyeccion.Text, NumberStyles.Any | NumberStyles.Number);`

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it in *two* steps:

1. Parse to `decimal`.
2. Cast to `int` (truncate or round).

For instance

```
// truncate: 80.97 -> 80
int value = (int) decimal.Parse(Txt_proyeccion.Text, NumberStyles.Any);

// round: 80.97 -> 81
int value = (int) Math.Round(decimal.Parse(Txt_proyeccion.Text, NumberStyles.Any));
```

**Edit:** You may want to specify *format* (e.g. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`) in order to be sure that `.` is the *decimal* separator while `,` is the *thousand* separator:

```
using System.Globalization;

...

// truncate: 80.97 -> 80
int value = (int) decimal.Parse(
  Txt_proyeccion.Text, 
  NumberStyles.Any,
  CulureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// round: 80.97 -> 81
int value = (int) Math.Round(decimal.Parse(
  Txt_proyeccion.Text, 
  NumberStyles.Any,
  CulureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, It doesn't work.

Vs says "'System.FormatException' inmscorlib.dll"

Comment: @Rafael Mauricio Villalta Varga: what's going wrong?

Comment: When the number tries to convert, .net show a message from library and stopped

Comment: @Rafael Mauricio Villalta Varga: What is the message? Try specify `CulureInfo.InvariantCulture` - see my edit - to be sure that separators are `.` and `,`

Comment: @Rafael Mauricio Villalta Varga: `using System.Globalization;`

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth people are converting to string and back to a number I have no idea.

```
float cash = 800000.49;
int number = (int)cash;
```

OR

```
int number = (int)Math.Floor(cash);
```

OR

```
int number = (int) Math.Round(cash);
```

You get the idea.